# Where can I get more resource cards?

Tags: godus

I am struggling to find more resource cards. I have a population of 4500 spread over quite a large area, and I've over all of my land looking for treasure chests but I appear to be collecting society cards from growing my population far faster than resource cards:

[image]

Apart from treasure checks, what other methods are there are finding additional resource cards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the mentioned treasure chests (which are pretty frequent), there are also the faux-multiplayer battles in the temple. When you manage to win one, you get multiple cards, many of which are resources. Another option is purchasing the individual resources for gems in the book.

Comment: Treasure Chests, Alter of the gods (AI multiplayer), Multiplayer (alter with handshake), And you can purchase cards in the book itself (go into the resources pages and click the gem on the side of the card).

Comment: I totally forgot about purchasing resources for gems, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am also blocked after having played all the temple "multiplayer" games. It seems that you can only get more cards by playing real multiplayer after this.